# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: self.senderId != nil'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm playing with JSQMessagesViewController. My first project I did using Raywenderlich's [Firebase Tutorial: Real-time Chat tutorial.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2)

Then I created a new project to play more with JSQMessagesViewController. And in this new project I'm having issue now.

After I import JSQMessagesViewController and add it as a super class for my ViewController, I got this error in my console -

> Assertion failure in -[NewProject.ViewController viewWillAppear:],
>   /Users/Downloads/ChatChatFirebaseTutorial-finished/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m:233
>   2017-05-30 20:43:44.498 NewProject[10688:314277] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid parameter not satisfying: self.senderId != nil'

I see message from ChatChatFirebaseTutorial(am I right?) my previous project in my new project.

So, I deleted everything what was about ChatChatFirebaseTutorial and even more from my mac. It didn't help. I uninstalled and installed pods from project and mac few times. It didn't help.

Did anyone has this issue before? If yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: My issue was solved [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796471/how-to-push-a-jsqmessagesviewcontroller-correctly) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Library requires that you set a `senderID` for the current user. This can be done by adding a function like this to your class

```
override func senderId() -> String {
    return "UNIQUEID"
}
```

I would use something you know is going to be unique such as an email or a unique Id you generate just associated to the user so you can determine who sent the messages.